# I appear to have 'serial voted'. Would a moderator please explain the specifics so I can avoid doing it in the future?

Tags: discussion

When I logged on this AM, I found that I had been deduced 12 reputation points because "Serial Voting was Reversed". Would someone please explain what I did that triggered the deduction, so that I can avoid making the same mistake again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely didn't do anything to trigger it *directly*, though you have led to it indirectly.

By raising a flag earlier to notify moderators about a case of serial downvoting, I ended up escalating the issue to try and have reputations restored to normality, which itself led to a chain of events that eventually culminated in a point recount made by the system.

From then on what the system does is really a black box to us, it may lead to favorable or unfavorable results to an undetermined number of users.

If you report a rep loss, then I presume among other things the system considered you were perhaps being favored by some other user, which may intentionally or unintentionally have upvoted an abnormal amount of your posts.

Comment: I see. It's weird that I lost 12 reputation and that I never did get any reputation back from the case where I was the victim of extensive revenge voting, but such are the vagaries of complex systems.  Thanks for the explanation.